# Reduce dimension of armature

Tags: armature

I have bought this file and I would like to change the pose but it is very difficult. The bones are big and I can't see the figure. There is some command that I can use to reduce the dimension of the bones?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select the Armature, go to edit mode, select all bones, change the pivot point behaviour from "median point" to "Individual origin", then press S to scale the bones.

Works only for armatures that do not have bones connected one to the other (only "Keep Offset" type of parent/child relationships), but generally this is the case in armatures like your example.

[image]

Alternatively, in Pose mode you can assign any mesh as custom shape to the viewport display property of the bones, changing the loc, rot, scale, and wireframe mode. Press Alt while selecting the mesh to assign it to multiple selected bones.

[image]